# semantic-release fails to increase version

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, versioning, semantic-release

If there is any changes via merge from branch to master, we need semantic-release to analyse the commit message and increase the release version. We are using Bitbucket scm. The process of how we merge from branch to master, developer create a pull request, then the reviewer will review. If all is ok, reviewer will select **squash commit** and click merge. I try setting the `mergePattern` to include squash commit header on top of the default rules. However, it seems that semantic-release is still ignoring squash commit.

**package.json**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.0",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^11.0.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^11.0.0",
    "@semantic-release/changelog": "^5.0.0",
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer": "^6.3.3",
    "@semantic-release/exec": "^3.3.8",
    "@semantic-release/git": "^7.0.18",
    "@semantic-release/npm": "^5.3.5",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "commitizen": "^4.2.2",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "semantic-release": "^15.14.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  },
  "release": {
    "branch": "master",
    "repositoryUrl": "https://bitbucket.org/scm/owner/reponame.git",
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
        {
        "parserOpts": {
            "mergePattern": "/^Merge .* in .* from ([^\/]*).* to master$/"
          }
        }
      ],
      [
        "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
        {
        }
      ],
      "@semantic-release/npm",
      [
        "@semantic-release/changelog",
        {
          "changeLogFile": "CHANGELOG.md"
        }
      ],
      [
        "@semantic-release/git",
        {
          "message": "chore(release): ${nextRelease.version}",
          "assets": [
            "CHANGELOG.md",
            "package-lock.json",
            "package.json"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "@semantic-release/exec"
    ],
    "ci": "false"
  }
```

**Output from npx semantic-release --no-ci --debug**

```
[11:21:18 am] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] » i  Analyzing commit: Merge pull request #45 in owner/reponame from feature3 to master

Squashed commit of the following:

commit ad116843ba59f3f114a3c44772a3b7294255308a
Author: Tommy <tommy@hotmail.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 24 14:37:46 2020 +0800

    feat(rel): added create new user function

commit 52b1b0f9b0795b36706b840fb8c3ac2f950fa133
Merge: 8a87691 02069cf
Author: Tommy <tommy@hotmail.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 24 14:36:33 2020 +0800

    Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master' into feature3

commit 8a8769126d11aa8e42726f4209736a4a51f9b7f6
Author: Tommy <tommy@hotmail.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 24 12:13:00 2020 +0800

    feat(rel): added amend user function
  semantic-release:commit-analyzer Analyzing with default rules +14ms
[11:21:18 am] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] » i  The commit should not trigger a release
```